# Обработка EXE файл в браузере

Tags: браузер, exe

Как запустить или отобразить(или обработоть на сервере и отобразить в браузере)  exe файл в браузере?
Были ответы:

> Либо поставить сервер типа denwer, и поюзать волшебный файл .htaccess
>   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .exe Тогда в этой папке экзешники (запрос
>   вида http://123.122.121.120/scripts/my.exe) результат экзешника будет
>   выводиться в браузер

Это точно работает? Как проверить на винде, нельзя создать файл .htaccess

> При выполнении команды os.system "PATH/TO/EXE.EXE" в Python-сервере
>   будет исполняться исполняемый файл и вывод из stdout попадает на
>   страницу. Вроде, всё просто и легко выполняемо!

У меня вывелся только текст скрипта. Чтото не так сделал?

> Копаем в сторону CGI и виндус-хостингов. Прямо в браузере нельзя,
>   браузер не ось, да и небезопасно, а вот вывод вполне возможен. Вопрос
>   запуска личных экзешников лучше задавать хостеру в саппорт перед
>   покупкой хостинга :)

Приведите рабочие примеры и принцип их работы

***Вообще напишите рабочие примеры, что нибудь работает?***

***Напишите что думайте про эти ответы пожалуйста и напишите свои и примеры к ним, если можно***

Comment: `на винде нельзя создать файл .htaccess` вообще-то можно, почему нельзя?

Comment: винда не даст создать, можно с невидимым символом, думаю работать не будет, а вы знаете? расскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Все три ответа правильные, просто вам не хватает знаний, чтобы понять ответ

Итак, самый простой вариант: просто пишем свой веб-сервер. Запускаем. Получается как вам нужно - выполняется EXE файл и в браузере по адресу http://127.0.0.1/ вы видите то, что пишет ваш EXE в ответ на запрос по порту TCP 80 (стандартный HTTP порт)

Что такое веб-сервер: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

Простенький пример веб-сервера на C++ и сокетах в один поток: https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-http-server-over-sockets/ (Windows, с разбором и теорией, рекомендую прочитать)

Теперь вы можете написать и собрать такой EXE файл, который отдаст браузеру все что вы хотите и так, как вы хотите. Но учтите, что кроме как с вашего ПК, где запущен этот EXE, более никто не увидит этого

Запускать EXE-файлы на хостингах вам никто не даст из соображений безопасности, ну и бессмысленности тоже. Максимум, вы можете арендовать что-то вроде VPS/VDS с Windows на борту (не дешевое удовольствие) и закачать туда свой EXE и запустить уже там

Если вас такой вариант не устраивает, прочитайте про языки вроде PHP и Python. Они позволяют сделать все, что вы собираетесь сделать в своем EXE, и даже немного больше. Но без всяких EXE файлов и на обычных хостингах.

Возможно ваша задача решается без всякого запуска EXE. Опишите лучше изначальную задачу, будет полезнее - вам смогут подсказать варианты решения задачи, а не одно конкретное решение с EXE, которое сильно отдает уроками информатики где-то в 2000 году

Comment: "пишет ваш EXE в ответ на запрос по порту"

Comment: "пишет ваш EXE в ответ на запрос по порту"                          Просто exe файл не обработает? Нужно специально писать куда выводит(типа в тег например <canvas>) и писать javascript отслеживания действий(например нажатия клавиши) и посылает приложению? Я правильно понимаю? Напишите поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: @АнимеЛюбитель, что значит "просто exe файл не обработает"? exe - это исполняемый (executable) файл с набором инструкций для операционной системы (в частных случаях - для оборудования вашего ПК). Браузер - не операционная система, он не запускает исполняемые файлы. Он просто рисует на экране текст и изображения со специальной разметкой, плюс исполняет текстовые скрипты (например, JavaScript). В современных браузерах также обычно есть проигрыватель аудио/видео. Но ничего из этого никак не поможет вам в запуске исполняемых файлов.

Comment: Браузер не умеет обрабатывать EXE файлы. Опишите изначальную задачу, ничего не понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать и зачем так сложно все

Comment: Нужно специально писать куда выводит(типа в тег например <canvas>) и писать javascript отслеживания действий(например нажатия клавиши) и посылает приложению? Я правильно понимаю? Ответе пожалуйста на конкретный вопрос                                                                                   
Просто теория

Comment: Нет, конкретно вы пишите абсолютный абсурд, canvas, javascript и отслеживание действий с посылкой EXE файлу для выполнения в браузере - это воспринимается как катастрофическое недоразумение и полное ваше непонимание предметной области

Comment: Если из вашего вопроса выбросить весь.. мусор по поводу EXE файла, то возможно вам будет полезна статья https://habr.com/post/184666/ , в которой описывается игра на JS и canvas. Демо игры можно посмотреть по адресу http://jlongster.github.io/canvas-game-bootstrap/ Может быть это то, что вам нужно?